# Given an optimal value, can you prove if its extremal?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let's say I have a multivariable function that I need to maximize over some constraints. If I know the relation between the variables where I believe the function is maximized, is there any way to prove it?

In detail; I have a function with three variables that I need to maximize under the condition that another function with the same three variables remains a constant. Numerically, I know that the maximum is achieved when all the variables are equal. I haven't been able to prove this analytically. Is there any way I can show that maximum is achieved when variables satisfy this condition?

The function and the constraints are all symmetric in the variables. Function, constraint and the variables lie in real valued interval.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the functions...

Answer (score 1):

Already in nonconvex quadratic programming, it is just as hard to prove that a point is optimal, as it is to find it. In other words, there is no simple cheap way in the general case to confirm optimality.

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167637788900491

For your particular problem and setup it might be easier, but then you would have to supply details.